# Installing Oracle 11g R2 Express Edition on Ubuntu 64-bit

Tags: 12.04, oracle

I'm attempting to use Oracle Express using http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.in/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html as a guide, but I run into an issue.

```
sudo cat /etc/sysctl.d/60-oracle.conf 
# Oracle 11g XE kernel parameters  
fs.file-max=6815744  
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=9000 65000  
kernel.sem=250 32000 100 128 
kernel.shmmax=536870912

sudo service procps start
procps stop/waiting
```

I verify the change,

```
sudo sysctl -q fs.file-max
fs.file-max = 65535
```

but `fs.file-max = 65535 =/= 6815744`

How do I make the change? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what I think about changing the `file-max` and `shmmax` just so a driver can work. To me that sounds like the start of a very abusive relationship. Have you tried just ignoring it and seeing if it works?

Comment: Yes, I tried ignoring it. Issues occurred later.

Answer (score 0):

Hiii, Guy's

if you have any problem to installing Oracle 11g Express Edition just follow this simple step: just keep it in mind instead of amit always use you computer user name: here all i did in my computer that same thing i am going to express in front of you}

amit@Deepin:~$ sudo apt-get update

{after completing this go for further process}

to check the group that already added and the group no. which avaliable:

amit@Deepin:~$ sudo cat /etc/group

to add group:

amit@Deepin:~$ sudo groupadd -g 801 oinstall

amit@Deepin:~$ sudo groupadd -g 800 dba

{here 800 is group no. and 'dba' is group name}

to find out group no.

amit@Deepin:~$ sudo cat /etc/group |grep -i 800 <---- it will check wheather 800 group no. already assign to some group or not.

after adding your group verify:

amit@Deepin:~$ sudo cat /etc/group
dba:x:800  <----- that mean the group has successfully added,....

to add an user who belong from two group:

amit@Deepin:~$ sudo useradd -u 800 -g dba -G oinstall -d /home/oracle oracle

to create passord for user:

amit@Deepin:~$ sudo -i

root@Deepin:~# sudo cat /etc/passwd

root@Deepin:~# sudo id oracle

root@Deepin:~#passwd oracle

new password *******

confirm password *******

to give ownership to an user for a directory:

root@Deepin:~#chown -R oracle:dba /home/oracle

we need to do change in startup Script:

root@Deepin:~# mkdir /etc/rc.d

root@Deepin:~# for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 S

**>do ln -s /etc/rc$i.d /etc/rc.d/rc$i.d**

**>done**

Now,
we will create the directory for installation, and change it owner to create

root@Deepin:~# mkdir -p /u01/app/oracle

root@Deepin:~# chown -R oracle:dba /u01

now, u can login as oracle user
root@Deepin:~# su oracle

$

$bash -i               <----- to provide bash command support

oracle@Deepin:/root$ su -

Password: *****

root@Deepin:~#

now again login as root and go to /home/oracle   ,,, where you copy settup

root@Deepin:~# unzip oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip

Install the following packages :

root@Deepin:~# apt-get install alien libaio1 unixodbc

The Red Hat based installer of Oracle XE 11gR2 relies on /sbin/chkconfig, which is not used in Ubuntu. The chkconfig package available for the current version of Ubuntu produces errors and my not be safe to use. So you'll need to create a special chkconfig script, below is a simple trick to get around the problem and install Oracle XE successfully:

root@Deepin:~# gedit /sbin/chkconfig

(copy and paste the following into the file )

**-------------------------------------**

**#!/bin/bash**

**# Oracle 11gR2 XE installer chkconfig hack for Deepin**

**file=/etc/init.d/oracle-xe**

**if [[ ! `tail -n1 $file | grep INIT` ]]; then**

**echo >> $file**

**echo '### BEGIN INIT INFO' >> $file**

**echo '# Provides: OracleXE' >> $file**

**echo '# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog' >> $file**

**echo '# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog' >> $file**

**echo '# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5' >> $file**

**echo '# Default-Stop: 0 1 6' >> $file**

**echo '# Short-Description: Oracle 11g Express Edition' >> $file**

**echo '### END INIT INFO' >> $file**

**fi**

**update-rc.d oracle-xe defaults 80 01**

**#EOF**

**-----------------------------------------------------------------**

Save the above file and provide appropriate execute privilege :

root@Deepin:~# chmod 755 /sbin/chkconfig

Oracle 11gR2 XE requires to set the following additional kernel parameters:

root@Deepin:~# sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.d/60-oracle.conf

(Enter the following)

---

**# Oracle 11g XE kernel parameters**

fs.file-max=6815744

net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=9000 65000

kernel.sem=250 32000 100 128

kernel.shmmax=1610612736

---

(Save the file)

Note: kernel.shmmax = max possible value , e.g. size of physical RAM ( in bytes e.g. 512MB RAM == 512*1024*1024 == 536870912 bytes and 1536MB RAM == 1536*1024*1024 == 1610612736)

Verify the change :

root@Deepin:~# sudo cat /etc/sysctl.d/60-oracle.conf

Load new kernel parameters:

root@Deepin:~# sudo service procps start

Verify:

root@Deepin:~# sudo sysctl -q fs.file-max

-> fs.file-max = 6815744

Increase the system swap space : Analyze your current swap space by following command :

root@Deepin:~# free -m

make some more required changes :

root@Deepin:~# sudo ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk

root@Deepin:~# sudo mkdir -p /var/lock/subsys

root@Deepin:~# sudo touch /var/lock/subsys/listener

Convert the red-hat ( rpm ) package to Ubuntu-package :

root@Deepin:~# sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm

Go to the directory where you created the ubuntu package file in the previous step and enter following commands in terminal :

root@Deepin:~# sudo dpkg --install oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb

Do the following to avoid getting MEMORY TARGET error ( ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system ) :

root@Deepin:~# sudo rm -rf /dev/shm

root@Deepin:~# sudo mkdir /dev/shm

root@Deepin:~# sudo mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=2048m /dev/shm

(here size will be the size of your RAM in MBs ).

The reason of doing all this is that on a Ubuntu system /dev/shm is just a link to /run/shm but Oracle requires to have a seperate /dev/shm mount point.

To make the change permanent do the following :

create a file named S01shm_load in /etc/rc2.d :

root@Deepin:~# sudo gedit /etc/rc2.d/S01shm_load

Then copy and paste following lines into the file :

---

**#!/bin/sh**

case "$1" in

start) mkdir /var/lock/subsys 2>/dev/null

touch /var/lock/subsys/listener

rm /dev/shm 2>/dev/null

mkdir /dev/shm 2>/dev/null

mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=2048m /dev/shm ;;

*) echo error

exit 1 ;;

esac

---

Save the file and provide execute permissions :

root@Deepin:~# chmod 755 /etc/rc2.d/S01shm_load

This will ensure that every-time you start your system, you get a working Oracle environment.

You can now proceed to the Oracle initialization script

root@Deepin:~# sudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc

---

export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe

export ORACLE_SID=XE

export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`

export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

---

Enter the following configuration information:
A valid HTTP port for the Oracle Application Express (the default is 8080)
A valid port for the Oracle database listener (the default is 1521)
A password for the SYS and SYSTEM administrative user accounts
Confirm password for SYS and SYSTEM administrative user accounts
Whether you want the database to start automatically when the computer starts (next reboot).
Before you start using Oracle 11gR2 XE you have to set-up a few more things :

a) Set-up the environmental variables, add following lines to the bottom of /etc/bash.bashrc :

b) execute your .profile to load the changes:

root@Deepin:~# source /etc/bash.bashrc

root@Deepin:~# cd ..

Start the Oracle 11gR2 XE :

root@Deepin:~# sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure

root@Deepin:~# sudo service oracle-xe start

The output should be similar to following :

root@Deepin:~# service oracle-xe start

Starting Oracle Net Listener.

Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.

root@Deepin:~#

Comment: please [format](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) you answer.